# Animate Zoom and Cropout an Imageview in android

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

Can someone help me creating this animation. I tried `ScaleAnimation` but that didn't help at all

Here is the animation

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a long answer, but I guess that is what you want.

**Preview** - https://giphy.com/gifs/S78V44TmVHrXOrrkQH

style.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/CustomActivityAnimation</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomActivityAnimation" parent="@android:style/Animation.Activity">
        <item name="android:activityOpenEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_in_right</item>
        <item name="android:activityOpenExitAnimation">@anim/slide_out_left</item>        
    </style>
```

Create an anim folder and create two anim files

**slide_in_right.xml**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate android:fromXDelta="100%p" android:toXDelta="0"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
```

**slide_out_left.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="-100%p"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
</set>
```

**All the code above will be used for transition between two activity**

**And now let`s create animaton of black image with Motion Layout. In order to use motion layout first we need to implement dependency**

```
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta6'
```

**In order to use Motion Layout in our layout we should make root layout MotionLayout**(On Design page of your layout find Component Tree and  right click on your root layout, and then there you will see option saying 'Convert to MotionLayout'. It is recommended to do in that way. Because it automatically generates xml folder which holds `MotionScene`)

**activity_main.xml**

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layoutDescription="@xml/activity_main_scene"
        android:background="#fff"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
    
    
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/iame" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
```

**activity_main_scene.xml (It must be in 'xml' folder which is also inside 'res' folder. If it is not auto generated, you must generate yourself)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Transition
        motion:autoTransition="animateToEnd"
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end"
        motion:constraintSetStart="@id/start"
        motion:duration="2000">
       <KeyFrameSet>
           <KeyAttribute
               motion:motionTarget="@+id/imageView"
               motion:framePosition="21"
               android:scaleX="5"
               android:scaleY="5"/>
           <KeyAttribute
               android:scaleX="10"
               android:scaleY="10"
               motion:framePosition="40"
               motion:motionTarget="@+id/imageView" />
           <KeyAttribute
               android:scaleX="20"
               android:scaleY="20"
               motion:framePosition="100"
               motion:motionTarget="@+id/imageView" />

       </KeyFrameSet>
    </Transition>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">
    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">
    </ConstraintSet>
</MotionScene>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // do something...
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Second.class));
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);

        }
    }, 2000);

}}
```